# net.tcp Throws Exception with (Apparently) Solid .config <systerm.serviceModel>

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015, wcf-binding, net.tcp, iis-10

I think I've tried everything, but I can't get a simple net.tcp WCF service to work and I need a bit of help.  I have a WCF net.tcp project in Visual Studio 2015 with the following service class:

```
namespace AppRefactory.JdmCommSample
{
    public enum DocType { Labels, Releases, Artists }

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILabelOperations
    {

        [OperationContract]
        bool PassLabelProcess(string targetAddress, string hostCommand, MusicLabelContract musicLabel);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
}
```

And the following implements the service in a file LabelProcess.svc:

```
namespace AppRefactory.JdmCommSample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "MusicLabel" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select MusicLabel.svc or MusicLabel.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class LabelOperations : ILabelOperations
    {
        public bool PassLabelProcess(string targetAddress, string hostCommand, MusicLabelContract musicLabel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I've done extensive reading on the web.config for the service and haved used ServiceModelReg.exe to help me - but the following is the current edition of the service project's web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="epTcpBehavior">
          <endpointDiscovery />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorConfig">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"
            includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
        <add binding="netTcpBinding" scheme="net.tcp" bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfig" name="AppRefactory.JdmCommSample.LabelOperations">
        <endpoint address="LabelService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp"
          name="LabelOperations" contract="AppRefactory.JdmCommSample.ILabelOperations" />
        <endpoint address="netTcpMex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          name="NetTcpMEX" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="mexhttp" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="HttpMex"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/JdmCommSample/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="InsecureTcp" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <mexTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" />
      </mexTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I go to the client project and attempt to add the service reference (in Visual Studio 2015), I am getting the following error:

[image]

The 'Discover' button doesn't reveal the service when clicked, so I manually enter the service address: net://localhost/JdmCommSample/LabelOperations.svc and get the following result clicking the 'Go' button:

[image]

Finally, I click the 'Details' link in the error message block (within the dialogue) above and get the following:

Add Service Reference Error Dialogue:

> The URI prefix is not recognized.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/JdmCommSample/LabelOperations.svc'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost/JdmCommSample/LabelOperations.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I have been receiving this same error message now for quite a while and cannot figure out why the metadata for the client keeps insisting on using the old http:// address for the service and why it won't accept the net.tcp address.

Finally, I should just quickly add I'm using the following as my dev environment:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Windows 10
- IIS 10

...and I've taken the time to try solving this issue by amending IIS settings with the Default service supporting net.tcp (both with and without http) and creating a virtual application in the /bin and coding folders in order to support interactive debugging.  The error message described in the final dialogue above changes - but only to say that the net.tcp:// address I'm using is 'unavailable'.

Again, your help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Please include the linked images inline rather than as hyperlink. One of them is not accessible. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow restricts images so I can only link externally, at this point — unfortunately.  I will try to fix the broken image link at my end; and if you could just click on the two links above in responding - it only takes a couple of seconds if you look in your browser's newly-opened image tab.

Thanks!

Comment: One quick note about "Add Service Reference Dalogue - B" in the images list; it says "net://" at the start of the Address bar.....but I was getting this error message regardless of net.tcp:// being correctly added.

Comment: Just a question... Is there any particular reason you are using generated proxies rather than just calling the service directly? It seems to me that your problem could be circumvented altogether. Generating a service reference to call a service should only be done under certain restrictive conditions.

Comment: Tom - looks like you hit the nail on the head. Simply declaring the endpoint and referencing it from the client directly solved the problem. I posted the following in another forum concerning my discovery of the problem: 

[MSDN WCF Forum Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f58933c4-03c2-49d2-898d-73f465e4c046/nettcp-throws-exception-with-apparently-solid-config-systermservicemodel?forum=wcf#14366c10-042f-44de-bdd1-d11f131f2b7a)

Answer (score 1):

Okay - so it looks as if I've solved this mess.....and the problem here is - I have not used Visual Studio for configuration of a net.tcp endpoint in many years and wrongly concluded with the absence of the WCF test service that used to sit in the system tray one would use the Add Service Reference dialogue to configure net.tcp linkages.

According to the MSDN Library article concerning setting up a net.tcp service via Windows Process Activation (WAS), all endpoint configuration and service references are handled using either hand-crafted or tool-generated code (using svcutil.exe) on the client — and largely hand-crafted logic on the service-side.

Thus my questions in this thread were the result of poor expectations and misinformation.  Apologies...

The next step here is to create a one-way service method that will have the effect of throwing an event up on the client.  I expect there will be questions posted here in the days ahead on that subject - if anyone has any useful links to share on that topic, please don't keep 'em to yourself! ;)